# How to notify the parent class about its object modification from other child class in java?

Tags: java

There are classes as shown below :

```
class Class1 {
    //object has been created here
    Object obj=new Object();
}

class Class2 extends Class1 {}
class Class3 extends Class2 {}
...
...
// there are 99 classes like above which extends its previous parent 
class Class99 extends Class98 {
    //Here we are modifying Class1's Object obj
}
```

How to notify Class1 that the Object obj which belongs to your class has been modified by Class99?
Please ignore if there are some logical or compilation errors.

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

This would violate the *information hiding* principle. The class holding the object should provide methods to manipulate the object (**not** *getter/setter*).

Any other class that needs to modify the object must use one of this methods regardless if it is a descendant or not.

---

But there is an exception:

If the class (and all of its descendants) are pure *data transfer objects* not having any business logic then you may expose `obj` through *getter/setter* methods.